# Using Latitude, Longitude, Bearing and Distance to get resulting coordinates giving inconsistent elliptical behaviour

Tags: python, gis, latitude-longitude, haversine

I have the following inputs

1. Latitude and Longitude in decimal notation
2. Bearing (in degrees), distance in km

I want to find out the latitude and longitude of the point which lies at the specified distance and bearing from the original point (I'm looking using distances in the range of 0-1000 meters, and the location is pretty close to the equator).

I used the following function

```
def calculate_destination_point(lat, lon, distance, bearing):
    """Input: latitude, longitude, distance in kilometers, bearing of line
    Output: lat, long of the points at specified distance and bearing.
    """
    # Constants
    radius = 6371  # Radius of the Earth in kilometers

    # Convert distance to radians
    distance /= radius

    # Convert bearing to radians
    bearing = math.radians(bearing)

    # Convert latitude and longitude to radians
    lat_rad = math.radians(lat)
    lon_rad = math.radians(lon)

    # Calculate destination point latitude
    dest_lat = math.asin(math.sin(lat_rad) * math.cos(distance) +
                         math.cos(lat_rad) * math.sin(distance) * math.cos(bearing))

    # Calculate destination point longitude
    dest_lon = lon_rad + math.atan2(math.sin(bearing) * math.sin(distance) * math.cos(lat_rad),
                                    math.cos(distance) - math.sin(lat_rad) * math.sin(dest_lat))

    # Convert latitude and longitude back to degrees
    dest_lat = math.degrees(dest_lat)
    dest_lon = math.degrees(dest_lon)

    return dest_lat, dest_lon
```

For inputs

```
bearing: 45
distance(km): 0.02
Source: 78.720249,9.944548
```

My output is

```
Destination Lat Lon: 78.72037618257347,9.945198229935736
```

I'm able to validate the distance with haversine's formula and the bearing using

```
def calculate_bearing(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    lat1_rad = math.radians(lat1)
    lat2_rad = math.radians(lat2)
    lon_diff_rad = math.radians(lon2 - lon1)

    y = math.sin(lon_diff_rad) * math.cos(lat2_rad)
    x = math.cos(lat1_rad) * math.sin(lat2_rad) - math.sin(lat1_rad) * math.cos(lat2_rad) * math.cos(lon_diff_rad)

    bearing_rad = math.atan2(y, x)
    bearing_deg = math.degrees(bearing_rad)
    bearing_deg = (bearing_deg + 360) % 360

    return bearing_deg
```

But when I convert these coordinates to a KML file and plot it, the following happened
For bearings 0 and 180, the measured distance in google earth showed up as the correct 0.02 value, but for bearings 90 and 180, it showed up 0.10, and for 45, it was 0.07.

There seems to be some sort of elliptical behaviour around a single point. As the bearing increases from 0 to 180, the coordinate returned is further away from the source point.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using to get the elliptical behaviour. The main thing to note is that only the bearing is changing.

```
    lat1, lon1 = 78.720249,9.944548
    distance = 0.02
    kml = simplekml.Kml()
    for bearing in range(0,360,15):
        coords = calculate_destination_point(lat1,lon1,distance,bearing)
        kml.newlinestring(name=f"Bearing:{bearing}",coords=[(lat1,lon1),coords])
    
    kml.save('../nalla/kml_practice/kml_dummies/elliptical.kml')
```

I've attached a screenshot of the behaviour.

[image: For the same source point and distance, but varyin bearing, the resulting points are varying.]

If this is normal behaviour then how do I correct it? And if it isn't could someone find the fault?

What did I try: StackOverflow showed me a post about using GeographicLib, but that me an even bigger ellipse.

Part of me is wondering if I have the correct results but incorrect processing of it.

Here is the output from the GeographicLib-based functions. As you would observe, the calculated distance is the same, but when plotting it using KML, I'm getting an ellipse.
[Ellipses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGphP.jpg)
Endpoint Lat: 78.72058074864637 Endpoint Lon: 9.944548 Endpoint Bearing: 0 Endpoint Distance: 0.03704000000088827

Endpoint Lat: 78.72056944426299 Endpoint Lon: 9.94498687182839 Endpoint Bearing: 15 Endpoint Distance: 0.03704000000059051

Endpoint Lat: 78.7205363015523 Endpoint Lon: 9.945395832808659 Endpoint Bearing: 30 Endpoint Distance: 0.037040000000551486

Endpoint Lat: 78.72048357931116 Endpoint Lon: 9.94574701112629 Endpoint Bearing: 45 Endpoint Distance: 0.037040000000121844

---

Finally: Turns out the error was purely because of the ordering of lat longs. After looking at the code with a fresh mind, I was able to correct it with the help of the answer marked correct, and the comment from @Ture Palsson! Appreciate everyone's earnest reply and help!

Comment: You can represent the earth in several ways: a perfect sphere, an oblate spheroid (this is earth's actual shape, a sphere with the poles having a slightly smaller radius that the equator), and many others. It's likely that google earth is calculating the distance on a more accurate representation of the earth. You seem to be using formulas that are for a perfect sphere. Using GeographicLib will provide you with distances from formulas along an oblate spheroid, which will look like an ellipsoid.

Comment: @K.Shores: I do not think your explanation is correct: 1- we are speaking about 1000 meters, 2- why 180 degrees gives a worse result.  to @ WeReign: what are the unit you are describing? Often it is just floating point errors (so one should use the formulas on exact same form (same order, no simplifications).

Comment: I'd stick with using Geographiclib and ask the question again about that. Are you sure your KML file is correctly created? FInally add some example output points for us to look at

Comment: I haven't checked the details, but you say that you are close to the equator, but then you say `lat1, lon1 = 78.720249,9.944548` so you are confusing latitudes and longitudes *somewhere*...

Comment: @K.Shores I used geographiclib, it gave me a bigger ellipse for the same arguments. Just to confirm my case, how about you try the same function with your own set of coordinates and values? 

if google earth is calculating values more accurately, it should still give the same distance from a common point. And haversine confirms that all the points have the same distance

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi. My units are kilometers for length, and I've confirmed and repeatedly checked that my units are consistent

Comment: @TurePålsson, sorry for that, I got misled while making that remark

Comment: @IanTurton, I added the outputs you asked for. Also, is it possible that google earth is just plotting it wrong, it feels highly unlikely considering the fact that even google maps gave the same output (and in case of maps, I basically just plotted the points by hand)

Comment: Your new print-outs say "Latitude: 78.xxxx", but your screenshot shows an area at latitude 9° N. Again: you have your lats and lons flipped somewhere. I don’t know if this is the cause of your problem but, at the very least, it is confusing for everyone else.

Comment: @TurePålsson, you were right! it was the flipping of lat long! I flipped them in the source coordinates, and then finally in the KML plotting. It was difficult to keep track of all of the conventions since half the libs use lat,long, and the other half use long lat.

And I was surprised at how starkly different google earth and google maps were, which made it more difficult to work simultaneously. Their navigation and zooming controls are the opposite, their lat lon conventions are flipped too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
kml.newlinestring(name=f"Bearing:{bearing}",coords=[(lat1,lon1),coords])
```

The [SimpleKML docs](https://simplekml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/geometries.html#simplekml.LineString.coords) say that the order of the coordinates is lon, lat:

> The coordinates of the feature, accepts list of tuples.
>
> A tuple represents a coordinate in the order longitude then latitude.
> The tuple has the option of specifying a height. If no height is
> given, it defaults to zero. A point feature has just one point,
> therefore a list with one tuple is given.
>
> Examples:
>
> - No height: [(1.0, 1.0), (2.0, 1.0)]
> - Height: [(1.0, 1.0, 50.0), (2.0, 1.0, 10.0)]
> - Point: [(1.0, 1.0)] # longitude, latitude
> - Point + height: [(1.0, 1.0, 100)] # longitude, latitude, height of 100m

Comment: Hey @Nick Odell, that sure was part of the problem! But it wasn't the only place, I had one error while declaring the original lat,longs too (they were swapped).